# Ubuntu 16.04 menus are always displayed

Tags: unity, 16.04, system-settings, appmenu, menu-bar

I recently upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 LTS, and although the system works properly and is generally stable, there is an issue that bugs me.

For the windows that have a menu bar, it is always displayed, regardless of the value selected in the "menus visibility" setting. See figures below:

[image]
[image]

On a different system that I also upgraded, the menu is hidden properly when the setting is selected.

What can cause this behavior? Is there anything that I can do to fix it?

I tried resetting my unity settings with `unity --reset`, with `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and with `sudo apt install --reinstall unity` with no luck.

---

The result of the `dpkg -l indicator-appmenu` command is:

```
$ dpkg -l indicator-appmenu
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
rc  indicator-appm 13.01.0+14.0 amd64        Indicator for application menus.
```

Comment: In "Show the menus for a window", can you choose "In the menu bar" instead and see if that works?

Comment: @edwinksl: Tested it. Unfortunately nothing changes. The menu bar stays in the same position as in the screenshot.

Comment: @user000001 what is the output of `dpkg -l indicator-appmenu`?

Comment: @Anwar: Added the result of the command to the question.

Comment: @user000001 Added an answer. Let me know the result.

Comment: @Anwar: Thanks, I will test it as soon as I am back to the computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your system is missing the `indicator-appmenu` package. Without that package you won't get the application menu on the titlebar in Unity session.

And reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` package wasn't fixing the problem because for some unknown reason, this package wasn't included in the dependency list of `ubuntu-desktop` package for 16.04 (You can check it by using `apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop` command).

So, to fix the issue, install the package with this command

```
sudo apt-get install indicator-appmenu
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you nailed it! Installing the package and restarting the PC solved the issue.

Comment: I have a very similar problem, but it only happens with GTK apps like terminal and nautilus... Other apps like the text editor, chrome, work with the global menu just fine... It's very annoying as it also breaks my desktop a little bit as the nautilus menu is displayed on top of the wallpaper... It doesn's happen for all the userids in the system tho, which makes it even more weird. Do you know what may be causing this?